# Cannot connect to order Oracle database with Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework

I have created a project in ASP.NET MVC 5, with EF database-first and Oracle 12c. It runs ok. But now, I want to change to another server. But it always connects to the old server. I don't know why.

My `web.config` looks like this:

Old server runs ok:

```
<add name="Entities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/db.Model1.csdl|res://*/db.Model1.ssdl|res://*/db.Model1.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=XXX1;PASSWORD=PW1;USER ID=ID1&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

And now, I change to new server like this.

```
<add name="Entities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/db.Model1.csdl|res://*/db.Model1.ssdl|res://*/db.Model1.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=XXX2;PASSWORD=PW2;USER ID=ID2&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

But I don't know why: The project always connect to old database (this means, when I debug project, it always gets database from DATA SOURCE=XXX1). How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Search your entire project (`ctrl+shift+F` visual studio) for `DATA SOURCE=XXX1` to check where else that `connectionString` is declared.

Most likely you'll find that connection in Web.Debug.config. Change it to the correct data source value.

More about Web Config Transformation [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2009/05/05/web-deployment-web-config-transformation/) (if you are not familiar with it already..)